# hot water pressure in bathtub

Tags: plumbing

Works fine through rest of the house. Its a mobile home n the water pressure was fine until water lines froze. Have replaced tub fixture n checked for leaks. Anything else that I can check

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A few more sentences on what you mean, perhaps with a diagram, would really help us understand your question better.

Comment: Dnt have a diagram, I replaced entire bathtub faucet that runs through the tub n hooks to water lines underneath mobile home. Have hot water pressure in bathroom sink but only a trickle in the tub. Cold water pressure is fine

Answer (score 1):

Call the Plumber back in. Your symptom is indicative of an Anti-Scald Valve problem, since it's just that fixture. It could be that the new fixture wasn't flushed out of manufacturing debris & that ruined the fixture. Maybe this valve just needs adjusting or wasn't set at the factory. Or, maybe it's just plain defective or on recall & must have the cartridge replaced.